# Switching to ios 9 sdk gives exc_bad_access

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7

My program runs fine before installing xcode 7 and switch to ios 9.

now one of my views gives ***exc_bad_access(Code=2,...)*** :

[image]

enabling zombie mode and using instrument didnt help and debug still shows above error without any useful description.

after adding some nslog and breakpoint i find out ***"pushViewController"*** gives

error :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Ipad" bundle:nil];   
        }
       else
        {
storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Iphone" bundle:nil];
         }
AtestViewController *atvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AVC"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:atvc animated:YES];
```

nothing in code changed before i swtich to xcode 7 and ios 9 !!

and also my other pushViewController  in program works well and

the coding method is same like above one.